# Add ScrollView after CollapsingToolBar not working

Tags: java, android, xml

In my `CountryActivityInfo.java` I have a collapsing toolbar with both width and height set to `match-parent` so it can occupy the whole phone screen. When I scroll up the toolbar gets a fixed `200dp` height.

Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

I want to display, in that white screen that appears when the toolbar is collapsed, a **vertical scroll view with a text view inside**. How can I do that? I've tried this way:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/testeparainfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarDivider">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/backgroundcollapsedtoolbarinfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCountryInfoFoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCountryInfoEscuro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_pais_info"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbaridinfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNomePaisInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/testeparainfo"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="left|bottom" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInfoPais"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnArrowBackWhite"
            android:layout_marginBottom="111dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/imgCountryInfoFoto"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But, when I do this, the text view gets inside the collapsing toolbar and gets collapsed with the toolbar.
By the way, all the XML is wrapped up in a `Coordinator Layout`!!!

Comment: change your toolbar height to this android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the root to `CoordinatorLayout`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and then in `content_scrolling.xml` use `NestedScrollView` and `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` use this property for proper behaviour.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    ...
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` inside your `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code
you have to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInfoPais"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnArrowBackWhite"
        android:layout_marginBottom="111dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/imgCountryInfoFoto"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```